# Dynamically create tables or not

Tags: mysql

I have reviewed some q&a but thought something specific to my subject would help me get off the fence.

I have an app that calculates pricing based on several different formulas and hundreds of different material types.

> user A may use formula A and material A, B, C
>
> user B uses formula A and material A, B, C, + they want to add a
>   material that no one else uses Material unique_A

when user A is on the app he doesn't want to see user B's unique material.

I was thinking of using a unique table of materials for each user so that it is "faster??? more efficient??? to grab the list of materials, instead of trying to set up some sort of off, on function that grabbed only the materials the user wants from one global table.

Which way is better? One table or a unique table for each user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a table of all materials.

```
  materials = (id, name, other attributes...)
```

and a table of users:

```
  myusers = (id, name, etc....)
```

then you can have a table that basically represents the many to many relationship between these two:

```
  user_materials = (user_id, material_id)
```

You can then select the specific materials used by a user by joining these tables. Application wise, this arrangement is better than trying to create a table for each user. Queries will become difficult. This way you also have answer to the question: Which users are using material A?

Comment: Thanks Vincent. throwing in the relational table is not something i had thought about. This really helps me move forward!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have very few users, each with his own stable non changing items,
I don't see any sense in doing this.
Plus , most likely you will not get into performance issues
if you are talking about a domain of users and materials.
It's not like there are millions of either , right?

Answer (score 0):

One "best practice" for databases is to reduce information duplicity. Actually variations of that exists for just about any field of theory there is.

It would mean however that your approach of a unique table per user would not be a good idea.
Not only would it duplicate data, but maintaining such a database would become a gigantic task as the number of users increases.

I would prefer to have a global table of materials, a table of users and a table over which user want's which materials.

The 'one-table-approach' can be considered better because it reduces complexity, both in database and in the code which should access the database, and duplication of information.